# Using the Woodbury identity on a matrix expression

Tags: matrix, sympy, matrix-inverse

## tl;dr

How do you make sympy perform a substitution for the Woodbury matrix identity?

## Background

The code snippet below generates the matrix `mat`

```
import sympy as s

d=10
q=3

sigma = s.symbols("sigma")
W = s.MatrixSymbol("W",d,q)
Iq = s.Identity(q)
Id = s.Identity(d)

mat =Iq - W.T @ (sigma**2 * Id + W@W.T).I @ W
```

I want to compute the expression `mat.I`. This may be done via the [woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). The identity says `(A+U@C@V).I` is equal to `A.I - A.I@U@(C.I-V@A.I@U).I@V@A.I`. By using the substitutions `A = Iq`, `U = -W.T`, `C = (sigma**2 * Id + W@W.T).I`, `V = W`

The answer, after cancellation, become `Id + W.T@W`.

Normal [substition](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) cant handle this case, since it replaces a single symbol with other expressions... I'm looking for substituting a sub-expression (by manually identifying A,U,C,V as above), or possibly a "pattern", for a expression that depends on the pattern.

In a sense this is like using regexp's with caputring groups for replacements.

## Question

How do I get sympy to compute `mat.I` yielding `Id + W.T@W` ?